# Telerik RadAjaxPanel returns 404

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to do a RadAjaxPanel ajaxRequest (invoked on the client) to call the server event-handler.  I'm getting a 404.  I do have a server-side AjaxRequest handler defined but it never gets call because of something with the request.  What do I have to do to figure this out?

.NET 4.0, IIS 7.5, latest telerik.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with Firebug or Fiddler (for IE) to see how the request is initiated and when happens afterwards. Also check the web.config configuration - whether the behavior changes with Classic or integrated IIS 7 pool.